# 3265 Run Time Error when retrieving table info

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

im getting the 3265 error on the second Forms! line the txtpsid line works fine. Queue, caseid, and repwrkdt are all valid fields in a table....

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sqlstr, sqlstr2 As String

Set db = CurrentDb()

sqlstr = "Select [RepID] From [TblFromRandomizer] Where Isnull ([Status])"

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sqlstr)

    Forms![FrmRcsQualityTool]![TXTPsid] = rs.Fields("RepID").Value
    Forms![FrmRcsQualityTool]![CMBQueue] = rs.Fields("Queue").Value
    Forms![FrmRcsQualityTool]![TXTItem] = rs.Fields("CaseID").Value
    Forms![FrmRcsQualityTool]![TXTItemdate] = rs.Fields("RepWrkDt").Value

Call search
```

Comment: What is the text of that error?

Comment: Run-tinme error '3265': Item not found in this collection, I've checked all the fields and their spelling (actually copying the field name and pasting into the vba code)

Comment: Break at that line, mark the right part of the assignment and press Shift+F9 or copy it to the immediate window, precede with a question mark and press enter. What happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Queue] field is not in the recordset because you didn't include it in your SELECT statement. When you run your SQL code you only retrieve the [RepID] field. You need to add the other fields to the column list in your SQL statement, e.g.,

```
SELECT [RepID], [Queue], [CaseID], [RepWrkDt] FROM [TblFromRandomizer] ...
```